# Understanding SD card read sequence in SPI mode

Tags: arduino, sd-card, spi

I'm trying to understand how data is read from an SD card in SPI mode, down to the lowest level (because of an upcoming project of mine).

**My setup:**
Arduino with SD.h library connected to standard SD card breakout with a logic analyser connected to important pins.

**What I know so far:**
I went through the initialisation process and I totally understand it now, but when it tries to read I get a little lost;

After the card init is done, the program tries to read from the address 0 with command CMD17: [image: Logic capture] and after this follows some data: [image: Logic capture 2]

What is weird, is that I could not find what this section of data is representing, it does not appear anywhere in the hexdump of the whole SD card. Only on the second read from the Arduino, at address 0x2000 I get the starting data from the hex dump I'm expecting:
[image]
And the beginning of the data packet:
[image: Logic capture 3]

My card is 32G, which is probably SDHC. I should point out that I'm just observing what apparently works and I'm trying to figure out why is that.

**My question** is, what the data from address 0 meant and why the "start" is at address 0x2000, even if my hexdump shows this data at address 0 (sector 0).

Comment: Are you sure your card officially supports SPI mode?

Comment: @0andriy well, the Arduino sketch works, so I'm not sure how official it is, but my main question is about the sectors - why address 0x2000 resulted in reading the first sector (sector 0) and the first read of address 0 gave me something I could not recognise nor find anywhere in the SD card hex dump

Comment: I guess the answer to that you should look in the SD protocol specifications. I can speculate about some error correction or security block, or bad blocks data, I dunno...